# Why even after installing express.js globally I still cannot run the file using express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Below code when attempted to execute via `node _filename_` still results in 'cannot find module 'express.js''

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.listen(
  3001,
  console.log(() => {
    "server is up and running on port 3001";
  })
);
```

Comment: You should install `express` in your local modules.

Comment: run `npm init` --> `npm i express`